# Warning script not working on Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, explorer

I created a website where it's mandatory to inform viewers if they are leaving the website. I'm using JavaScript for this function. The problem I have is it won't work on Explorer 11. Or, more specifically, I received a report from my customer informing me the exact version of Explorer they are using is 11.0.9600.18738.

I have tested this site on all of my versions of Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, mobile device (several browser versions) and my tablet, and it is functioning properly except, of course, the version of Explorer reported by my customer.

I have a screen capture from my customer:
[image]

The code I have for the links looks like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:external('http://www.ccenterdispatch.com/')" target="_blank" title="Visit Clay Center Dispatch Newspaper website, local newspaper and community pages."><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Clay Center Dispatch (Local newspaper and community pages)</a>
```

When this customer makes the selection on their version of Explorer this is what comes up as the URL (as shown in the screen capture):

```html
javascript:external('http://www.ccenterdispatch.com/')
```

Which, of course, doesn't exist.

Comment: What does the `external()` function do?

Answer (score 1):

`external` is a built-in object in IE.
Use a different function name.

Also, `target="_blank"` won't run URLs in your own context, so you can't call functions like that at all.
You should use a click event handler instead.